# Getting data from Dataframe and passing it into a new empty DataFrame

Tags: python, linux, pandas, ubuntu

I have a DataFrame that reads from a csv file.
I used loc function to get data from the first csv file successfully. My problem is that I'm unable to add the data I got from the first csv file to add to a new DataFrame.

```
import csv
import socket
import pandas as pd
import ipaddress
import numpy as np


print("Reading data from original csv...")
originaldata = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

sip_data = originaldata.sip

dip_data = originaldata.dip

print("Reading from asn csv...")
asndata = pd.read_csv("asn_ip(4).csv", delimiter = ';')

asn_data = asndata.IP

print(asn_data.head())

newdf = pd.DataFrame()

print("Processing data...")
for sip in sip_data:
    print("In for loop for sip in sip_data")
    find = False
    index = False
    for IP in asn_data:
        print("In for loop for IP in asn_data")

        IP_u = unicode(IP)
        print("IP_u = " + IP_u)
        print("IP = " + IP)
        sip_u = unicode(sip)
        print("sip_u = " + sip_u)

        if ipaddress.ip_address(sip_u) in ipaddress.ip_network(IP_u):
            print("Address found")
            info = asndata.loc[asndata['IP'] == IP_u].head(1)
            print(info)

            newdata = pd.DataFrame({"IP": IP}, index=[0])
            newdf.append(newdata)

        else:
            print("Not found")
```

After I run this code, the dataframe is still empty.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The column names for the first df are sip, port and datetime.
The column names for the second df are IP, ASN and Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append does not do the operation in place. You want something like:

```
newdf = newdf.append(newdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the newdf at the beginning of the loop :

```
e.g. 
newdf = pd.DataFrame({"IP": '1.1.1.1'},index=[0])
```

The loop should be able to then append the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

It is probably more efficient to instantiate an empty list outside the loop, append the newly created dataframes to this and then outside the loop use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the list you just filled with dataframes.

By the way, I am not sure using `index=[0]` is a good idea. All the rows in the newly created dataframe will have an index value of 0, which will make the index de facto useless.

Pseudo code below:

```
newdf_list = []

for sip in sip_data:
....
    newdf_list.append(pd.DataFrame({"IP": IP}, index=[0]))

newdf = pd.concat(newdf_list)
```